# Unable to read a cab file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to read a file named Data.csv using the code: pd.read_csv("Data.csv") through pandas but it is showing  'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File does not exist:

Even though I have the file in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided, my best guess is that the directory containing your file `'Data.csv'` isn't your python working directory (most of the time, it corresponds to the directory from which you executed your python script).

If you're not sure, here's an easy way to check what your python working directory is:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Now, let's say your working directory is `~/projetct` and your file is located here: `~/projetct/files/Data.csv`

You can open your file by using `pd.read_csv("./files/Data.csv")`